# apply css class to all instances

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to style some autogenerated html.  I built a system that allowed me to overlay bootstrap on this autogen stuff and now I want to do some tweaking of whats there.

the autogen produces stuff like this

```
<dl>...</dl>
```

Now I want to apply bootstraps `dl-horizontal` class to that generated tag.  Since its generated, I can't simply class it, I can't ID it, nothing.  It has to be purely CSS selectors, which is something I know very little about.

What would a CSS tag that does this look like?

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery to add a class to your `<dl>` tag like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("dl").addClass("dl-horizontal");
});
```

---

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $("dl").addClass("dl-horizontal");
});
```

```css
.dl-horizontal {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/795fptxw/3/)**.

Comment: +1 because you need jQuery for Bootstrap anyway. This is what I do with form plugins so I don't have to open the php and stick the class on stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in css to add a class. But you can use children selectors to format if all your elements are the children of the same parent.

For example if your elements are a children of the parent body then:

```
body > dl
{
    color : red;
}
```

The above code will change the text - color of all the  elements that are the children of